# Get Berkshelf to resolve cookbook in same repository

Tags: chef-infra, berkshelf

I have a single chef-repo with 2 cookbooks, say `cookbook-A` and `cookbook-B`, and a local Chef server.

`cookbook-A` depends on cookbooks from Chef Supermarket, `berks install` and `berks upload` run happily and the cookbook is now on the server.

E.g.

```
chef-repo
    /cookbooks
        /cookbook-A
            /cookbook-B
```

`cookbook-B` depends on more things from supermarket plus `cookbook-A`. When running `berks install` it cannot resolve `cookbook-A`

How can I tell it to resolve this one cookbook from the same directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in your Berksfile:

```
cookbook 'cookbook-A', path: '../cookbook-A'
```